# ld: can't open output file for writing

Tags: linker, fortran, ld

I'm using MacBook M1 and Following is the make file for the Fortran code:

```
# This is the Make file for the 1D McCormack Code.

# To find paths to libraries:
# sudo update-alternatives --list liblapack.so3
# sudo update-alternatives --list libblas.so3
# or
# whereis blas
# whereis lapack

vpath %.f90 src

FC = gfortran

FFLAGS = -g -fcheck=all -Wall -fbacktrace
#FFLAGS = O2

BIN = /Desktop/Research/bin
MOD = include
OBJ = obj
SRC = src

SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.f90
OBJECTS = vars.o   idata.o   grids.o   mac1d_sch.o   fieldinit.o   coder.o   postpr.o   mac1d.o
MODULES = vars.mod idata.mod grids.mod mac1d_sch.mod fieldinit.mod coder.mod postpr.mod 

.PHONY: clean, cleano

# Add path to all files in OBJECTS. Note: no space after opening parenthesis!
OBJS = $(patsubst %.o, $(OBJ)/%.o, $(OBJECTS) )

print-% : ; @echo $* = $($*)

$(BIN)/MAC1D:   $(MODULES) $(OBJECTS)
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(BIN)/MAC1D

#-L/usr/lib/lapack:/usr/lib/libblas -llapack -lblas 
#WAVE:  $(MODULES) $(OBJECTS)
#   gfortran -O2 $(OBJECTS) -o WAVE

%.o:    %.f90
    $(FC) -I$(MOD) -c $(FFLAGS) $<
    mv *.o obj

%.mod:  %.f90
    $(FC) -J$(MOD) -c $(FFLAGS) $<

clean:  
    rm -f $(OBJ)/*.o $(MOD)/*.mod $(BIN)/MAC1D

cleano: 
    rm -f $(OBJ)/*.o
```

I'm getting the error:

```
ld: can't open output file for writing: /Desktop/Research/bin/MAC1D, errno=2 for architecture arm64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can also share the Directories if needed.

Comment: I think you have a problem with your BIN-variable. Is the folder `/Desktop` really sitting at the root of your file system? I don't think so.

Comment: I changed the bin directory to /User/urmish/desktop/Research/bin
getting the same error.

Comment: I know a similar problem exists but I don't understand what to change in my makefile.

Comment: Could you update your question accordingly, including the error message?